# PHP "continue" stops foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, continue

This seems like a very stupid question, but without making any changes to the server.. the continue function in PHP seems to have started working incorrectly.

For example:

```
function contTest(){
    $testers = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
    foreach($testers as $test){
        echo "Got here<br>";
        continue;
        echo $test."<br>";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Got here
Got here
Got here
Got here
```

Whereas:

```
function contTest(){
    $testers = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
    foreach($testers as $test){
        echo "Got here<br>";
        echo $test."<br>";
    }
}
```

Ouputs:

```
Got here
1
Got here
3
Got here
4
Got here
5
```

I have used this function before and it did not seem to have this effect. Any ideas? Like I said, nothing on the server has changed so the PHP version is the same.

Comment: code works right. what you need?

Comment: Continue is working how it should http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: As far as I am aware, the function of 'continue' is to bypass the remainder of the code within the code block and start the next iteration of the loop.  So it appears to be doing its job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don’t know what effect you want, but this example is working correctly. `continue` needs to break current iteration and go to the next without executing code below this operator. And this function works in this case all the time since PHP 4.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to understand how continue works. i wanted to add some, so that if some body else confronts the same, may have this as reference.

You need to use the key word  **continue**  When you want ignore the next iteration of a loop. `continue is always used with if condition`

According to example here .

```
function contTest(){
    $testers = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
    foreach($testers as $test){
        echo "Got here<br>";
        **continue;**
        echo $test."<br>";
    }
}
```

This works as expected and perfect and here is why. 
You are looping through the array $testers which has four elements inside and 
after getting every element , you are telling php to ignore the elements by  using 
**continue** and that is the reason why it will not output the elements of the array 
$testers.

Let me try to rewrite your Example here.

```
function contTest(){
    $testers = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
    foreach($testers as $test){
        echo "Got here<br>";
        if ($test == 1):
        continue;
        endif;
        echo $test."<br>";
    }
}

echo contTest();
```

I have just used `continue` if element is equal to 1, meaning that element will be 
skipped (ignored). 
The output  is :

```
Got here
Got here
3
Got here
4
Got here
5
```

As you can see 1 is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` basically says ignore the rest of the code after `continue` and start with the next step of the foreach loop. So the result you are getting is perfectly okay (see http://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.continue.php). There must be some other effect that changed your output.

Answer (score 0):

This is what continue does exactly:

continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration. 
-- http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php